# asp.net core data protection PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage SAS token

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-blob-storage

We're currently working on a project that's in Azure and I wanted to make use of the extension methods available to persist the data protection keys to Azure Blob Storage.

One of the methods provided accepts a URI with a sas token to establish the connection to the storage account. However, I'm curious as to how the connection could be re-established again once the SAS token expires. I have reviewed the source code and didn't see how that's possible.

It would be helpful if someone could shed some light on this.

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/416d8cd1ea098eb643b4258247af3448f5545c32/src/DataProtection/AzureStorage/src/AzureDataProtectionBuilderExtensions.cs

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of hardcoding it, you can get SAS token in startup (Also keep in mind that it will slow down your App startup). But this also mean that to pick up new key your app needs restart.
2. You can have it as a config parameter and with each deploy write PowerShell script to load new SAS token
3. Generate long term key and encrypt with [Keyvalt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-2.2) combined with Managed Service Identity (MSI), . (PS. I am not security expert so I am not sure if its 100% safe). So even someone obtain your key it will be encrypted.

Comment: So the sas token is not hardcoded and it will be fetched from key vault every time. However I’m trying to avoid app restarts to refresh sas token.  Was wondering if they a method that you can pass to it a func that will return a new sas token

Comment: @ayoubj well you can generate token for a year, and if you need you can encrypt it with keyvault in this case it will be secure.

Comment: @ayoubj btw to be sure sas token in keyvault its just SAS url to get read/write to storage , so what I am talking is to encrypt dataprotection key which will be saved into blob(By the way aspnetcore will rotate data protection key).

Comment: I’m not so much worried about encrypting the sas token. I wanted a way for the access to the storage account to keep working after the initial setup. There’s a private method that accepts a func of a blob object so I decided to create an extension method with same code. This way I can create a blob object with a refreshed sas token.